# How to use D'Alembert formula for Neumann boundary conditions on a finite interval?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a PDE to solve that I am not sure how to do. I know how to solve this using D'Alembert's formula for Dirichlet boundary conditions but I do not know how to solve it for Neumann boundary conditions.

> Evaluate $u(\frac{5}{a},0.3)$ if $u$ satisfies $$u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}, \quad 0<x<1,\quad t>0$$ $$u(0,x)=x(1-x), \quad u_t(0,x)=0, \quad 0\le x\le 1$$ $$u_x(t,0)=u_x(t,1)=0, \quad t>0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'Alembert's formula   requires an appropriate extension of the initial values to the entire line $\mathbb R$.

- for Dirichlet conditions, you would use *odd* periodic extension: first $f(-x)=-f(x)$, then $f(x+2m)=f(x)$ for all integers $m$.
- for Neumann conditions,  use *even* periodic extension: first $f(x)=-f(x)$, then $f(x+2m)=f(x)$ for all integers $m$.

Dealing with the periodic extension is very painful if you need a complete formula for $u$. But here you are just asked to find the value at $x=0.3$ and $t=5/a$. This means
$$\frac12 (f(0.3+5)+f(0.3-5))$$
Use the periodicity and even-ness: 
$$f(5.3)=f(3.3)=f(1.3)=f(-0.7) = f(0.7)$$
and so on.

Comment: What about mixed boundary conditions ? i.e. u(t,0)=du/dx(t,1)=0 or du/dx(t,0)=u(t,1)=0